Constructing measurable sets out of the unit square
We know that for a Lebesgue measurable set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, any of its translates $x+S$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable with $m(x+S) = m(S)$. I am wondering about properties of higher-dimensional sets that follow a similar reasoning.
Set $S = [0, 1]^2 = [0, 1] \times [0, 1]$. Denote $S_y = \{x: (x, y) \in S\}$ (the part of $S$ at height $y$). My question is what happens if I translate some of these $S_y$'s? Will I still be left with a measurable set, and if so does the measure of this new set agree with the measure of the original set?
To be explicit, I mean what happens if we take $$T = \left(S \setminus\bigcup_{y}(S_y \times\{y\})\right) \cup \bigcup_{y}((S_y + t_y) \times \{y\}),$$ where the union is taking over some set of $y$'s, will this set be measurable? Of course if we take the union over a set of measure $0$ then both questions have an answer of yes. Additionally, if we translate the whole set $S$, then of course both answers still have a positive answer of yes. However how about in other cases? It seems to me that one could produce a non-measurable set this way. Are there any examples anyone knows of?

If you make $y$ run over a non-measurable set $E$ and put $t_y=2$ for all $y$, then $$T\cap([2,3]\times \mathbb R)= (E+(0,2))\times[0,1],$$ which is not measurable. Hence $T$ is not measurable.

Do you mean to say $[2, 3] \times \mathbb{R}$ instead? I believe the way it is written the set on the left will be empty.

Yes, my bad. $ $

I see, so the intersection is really just the set $[2, 3] \times E$. However, this only shows that a subset of $T$ is not measurable right?

No. That's why I put the intersection. The intersection of two measurable sets is measurable. So if $T$ has non-measurable intersection with a measurable set, it cannot be measurable.

Follow up question: What if we impose a restriction on which $y$'s we are running over. In the example you gave it was a nonmeasurable set, however if it were measurable even then could the resulting set be nonmeasurable?

Yes, because you can encode all the badness in $t_y$. With the notation in the answer, you can take $t_y$ to be $2$ when $y\in E$ and $0$ when $y\not\in E$.

That makes sense! So either we can encode the nonmeasurability in $E$ or on the function $t_y$. I am curious then, is the only way to save the set $T$ is by having both $E$ and $t$ be measurable?

That's probably not enough. Even a continuous function can map a measurable set onto a non-measurable set.
